# calling function before return in python

Tags: python, csv

I made an insert data program when I didn't use the `if option == ""` no problem, the data was successfully saved to the CSV file, but when I used it (`if option == ""`) before return, the data wasn't saved. can anyone help me find a solution

my code :

```
        if not any(username in i['USERNAME'] for i in users):
            password = input("Masukan Password \t: ")
            level = "Admin"
            kode = kode_acak()
            tambah.writerow({'KODE' : kode, 'NAMA' : nama, 'USERNAME' : username, 'PASSWORD' : password, 'LEVEL' : level})

            #this is the problem
            option = input("\n\u2713 pendaftaran success, silahkan enter untuk lanjut login ")
            if option == "":
                admin()
            return

        else:
            print("Failed Username sudah dipakai, coba yang lain!")
            daftar()
            return
```

Comment: what does ```admin()```do?

Comment: Could you clarify what you are trying to archieve?

Comment: `return` does nothing in your program, you don't need to include it. That also makes the title of the post inaccurate...

Comment: Is option actually `""`? Could there be a newline there that you're not thinking of? `if not option.strip()` might be what you're looking for, as it removes any stray whitespace before checking if it's boolean-y false (the empty string).